# El producto seleccionado no logra aparecer en el DOM cuando se intenta recorrer el array mediante un for... of de una función en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, bucle-for, dom

En este código, aún cuando se selecciona el producto y aparece en la consola, trato de hacer que cuando el usuario seleccione el mismo, también aparezca seleccionado en el DOM, a través de la función agregarAFavoritos pero la función no hacía nada...

```
alert('bienvenidos a nuestro shop!')

const products = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Sombreros de playa', price: 2200, img: "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/72/93/4d/72934d54964866b482ebf79c2df60aeb.jpg" },
    { id: 2, name: 'velas aromaticas ', price: 600, img: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/b0/3f/09/b03f098563f5b493d3604c7dcd0fc01b.jpg' },
    { id: 3, name: 'cepillos de bambu', price: 1500, img: 'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/7e/84/f8/7e84f81cbee05ed2bd4f656c7b6ac9c2.jpg' },
    { id: 4, name: 'shampoo solido organico', price: 700, img: 'https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_752421-MLA41972998872_052020-W.jpg' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Aprende a surfear', price: 1800, img: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/26/bd/0f/26bd0fe84aa57566c756725917ceafcb.jpg' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Clases de yoga', price: 1000, img: 'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/53/a6/ec/53a6ec3daf4982031eea7284514a3630.jpg' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Medita frente al mar', price: 900, img: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a1/d5/2c/a1d52c2ba21a1ccf83ad2d497a6e3645.jpg' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Conoce tu carta natal', price: 2000, img: 'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/4e/b2/a7/4eb2a74ad161a50464600175699d97d0.jpg' }

]

let htmlCatalog = ''
for (const product of products) {
    htmlCatalog += `
       <div  class='col-3 '>

        <img class="product-image" src='${product.img}'/>
          <div class="product-especifics">
            <h3>${product.name}</h3>
            <p class="product-price" >$  ${product.price}</p>
            <br>
          <div class='btn-info btnAddCart shop-button' id='product-${product.id}'>Add to cart</div>

        </div>

        </div>
      `

}

const produtcsFavoritos = []
document.getElementById('catalog').innerHTML = htmlCatalog
const btns = document.getElementsByClassName('btnAddCart')
for (const btn of btns) {
    btn.onclick = addToCart
    //btn.onclick= agregarAfovritos
}

function addToCart(e) {
    const btn = e.target

    const id = btn.id.split('-')[1]

    const product = products.find(p => p.id == id)
    console.log('Bien!! acabas de elegir  ', product.name,)
    console.log('y su valor es de $$', product.price)
    alert('Elegiste ' + product.name)
}

function agregarAfavoritos(product) {
    for (const product of products) {
        htmlCatalog +=  `
      <div class="produtcsFavoritos">
        <div  class='col-3 '>
          <img class="product-image" src='${product.img}'/>
            <div class="product-especifics">
              <h3>${product.name}</h3>
                <p class="product-price" >$  ${product.price}</p>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      `
    }
}



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./estilos.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>shop</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="catalog" class="row"></div>
         
    </div>
    <div class="produtcsFavoritos" >

    </div>
```

Comment: Dato importante: Títutlo = idea general. Cuerpo del mensaje = detalles. Sugerencias en la estructuración de preguntas en SOes: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

prueba agregar el innerhtml en tu funcion de esta manera:

```
function agregarAfavoritos(product) {
   for (const product of products) {
    htmlCatalog +=  `
       <div class="produtcsFavoritos">
          <div  class='col-3 '>
          <img class="product-image" src='${product.img}'/>
          <div class="product-especifics">
             <h3>${product.name}</h3>
             <p class="product-price" >$  ${product.price}</p>
            <br/>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>`
    document.getElementById('catalog').innerHTML = htmlCatalog
   }
}
```

Otro que me llama la atencion es que tu funcion agregarAfavoritos no le estas haciendo el llamado, que deberia hacer el llamado, un boton? el cambio de algun input? o deberia llamarse cuando se carga la pagina?

Ejemplo de cuando el contenido de la pagina hay cargado

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', agregarAfavoritos(products),false);
```

Ejemplo con un `button`

```
<button type='button' id='btnejemplo' class='btn' onclick='agregarAfavoritos(products)'>Agregar favoritos</button>
```

Comment: la función debería hacer un llamado a un botón, pero se me olvidó copiar esa parte del código

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, prueba con eso.